# Como puedo utilizar mi Array JSON para introducirlo en un label (Swift 5)

Tags: php, json, swift

Soy principiante en programación swift y estoy realizando una app la cual recojo datos de una base de datos MySQL con una API Rest en php.

Recibo datos de sensores en JSON desde mi php y tengo ya todo configurado desde Xcode con el método JSONDecoder() para recibir dichos datos y decodificarlos (los cuales ya los imprimo por consola y me salen correctos).

Mi duda es la siguiente: ¿Cómo puedo utilizar esos datos que me llegan para introducirlos en un label? (Quiero introducirlos en un label solo para probar que se puede hacer, para posteriormente utilizar dichos datos en un gauge `MBCircularBarProgress`)

Os dejo como tengo mi petición URL ->

//getData.swift

```
struct SensoresRequest {
let requestUrl: URL


init() {
    self.requestUrl = URL (string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")!
}

func getData(completionHandler: @escaping (Result<[Sensores], SensoresError>) -> Void) {
                
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: self.requestUrl) { (data, response, error) in
        
        guard let data = data else {
            completionHandler(.failure(.dataUnavailable))
            return
        }
     
        do {
            let getSensores = try JSONDecoder().decode(GetSensores.self, from: data)
            completionHandler(.success(getSensores.sensores))
        } catch {
            completionHandler(.failure(.cannotProcessData))
        }
        
        
    }.resume()

                
}
}
```

//Data.swift

```
struct GetSensores: Decodable {
var sensores: [Sensores]

init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    var sensores = [Sensores]()
    var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
    while !container.isAtEnd {
        if let route = try? container.decode(Sensores.self) {
            sensores.append(route)
        } else {
            _ = try? container.decode(DummyData.self)
        }
    }
    self.sensores = sensores
}
}

private struct DummyData: Decodable { }

struct Sensores: Decodable {
var userId: Int?
var id: Int?
var tittle: String?
var body: String?

}

enum SensoresError: Error {
case dataUnavailable
case cannotProcessData
}
```

//ViewController.swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {



@IBOutlet weak var labelOutlet: UILabel!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
  //  getData()
        
   
    SensoresRequest().getData { result in
        switch result {
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        case .success(let sensores):
            let sensor = sensores[0]
            print(sensor.id, sensor.userId, sensor.body, sensor.tittle)

        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Debes asignar una variable global para almacenar la respuesta del `getData`

   ```
   @IBOutlet weak var labelOutlet: UILabel!

   var sensor = [Sensores]()
   ```
2. Asignas la respuesta del `getData` a esa variable:

   ```
   self.sensor.append(sensores[0])
   ```
3. Verifico que haya valores en la variable global:

   ```
   if self.sensor.count > 0 { }
   ```
4. Como la respuesta es un Optional debes validar y evitar hacer unwrap directamente; entonces utilizo `guard`:

   ```
   guard let resBody = self.sensor[0].body else { return }
   ```
5. Asignas el valor al label:

   ```
   self.labelOutlet.text = resBody
   ```

En el `switch` cuando la respuesta es satisfactoria debes agregar una llamada asíncrona para que la asignación del valor al label sea en el mismo hilo. Entonces todo unido quedaría así:

```
@IBOutlet weak var labelOutlet: UILabel!

var sensor = [Sensores]()//1

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    SensoresRequest().getData { result in
        switch result {
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            case .success(let sensores):
                self.sensor.append(sensores[0])//2
            //  print(sensor.id, sensor.userId, sensor.body, sensor.tittle)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if self.sensor.count > 0 {//3
                        guard let resBody = self.sensor[0].body else { return }//4
                        
                        self.labelOutlet.text = resBody//5
                    }
                }
                
        }
    }
}
```